# Fail to run npm install on local angular project

Tags: angular

Every time I run npm install on my local angular project I get the following errors:

```
C:\Projects\Angular>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/pemrouz/buble.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\elbal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-07T09_45_08_860Z-debug.log
```

I run a Windows 10 Home 64bit OS with the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>node -v
v12.13.1

C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
6.13.2

Angular CLI: 8.3.2
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.4
```

I followed the solutions in various posts like:
[npm local install fails on first try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492310/npm-local-install-fails-on-first-try)
[npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262322/npm-err-windows-nt-6-1-7601-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)
[Error: npm install -g angular-cli | npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046121/error-npm-install-g-angular-cli-npm-err-windows-nt-10-0-10586)
but none of them solved my problem. Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install shows error with git not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473680/npm-install-shows-error-with-git-not-found)

Comment: @Sam after installing git I get more errors such as gyp ERR! find Python and messages about cannot find python. Is python needed?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cd C:\Projects\Angular
git clone https://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git
cd buble
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing package-lock.json and then run npm install again.